# Shortcut key for Resharper powertoys

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

I was wondering if anyone knows how to enable shortcut for accessing the powertoys for resharper in Visual Studio 2010.  I've installed coding zen and my understanding was it was supposed to be assigned a short cut of <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> but it doesn't work for me.

Thanks,
Kip Garrison

Answer (score 0):

Kip, you can assign any shortcuts manually after installation (including Alt+Z).